# Doing inference without the whole Tensorflow dependency

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a saved model (*.pb file) and I would like to do inference using that.

I can easily do that when I `import tensorflow` but that looks like an overkill to me.

On Android for example, I can have `libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar` and `libtensorflow_inference.so` files that allow me to run the inference with my saved model without having the super large Tensorflow dependency.

How can I do that in Python?

I am using `pyinstaller` to package my app and because of Tensorflow dependency, my executable is 500 MB. I need to reduce that.

Is there a Python module that's only doing inference with the model?

Comment: You could check out https://www.tensorflow.org/lite

Comment: Does Tensorflowlite support models in pb files?

Comment: ...and, would I have the same accuracy with tflite?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing, mainly because tensorflow is so big, and I think OpenCV is the answer.
See the post below for an extensive tutorial about running models in OpenCV only.
https://learnopencv.com/deep-learning-with-opencvs-dnn-module-a-definitive-guide/#what-is-opencvv-dnn-module